# How to solve 'I found no database files--while read file something.aux'

Tags: bibliographies

Hi I am trying to include references into my paper but it keeps showing the following when I compile. I am using texstudio.
Message:
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
The style file: plain.bst
I found no database files---while reading file term paper.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Astrov"

My code is like this:

```
\documentclass[letter,scriptaddress,twocolumn, prl,showkeys]{revtex4}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amstext, amscd, verbatim, mathtools, graphicx, float, caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
This is my reference\cite[1]{Astrov}.
\bibliography{term paper}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

They are all in the same directory. I am really panicing about this at the moment and apologize if similar questions have been asked before. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So you have `term paper.bib` in the same folder? Avoid using spaces in filenames; rather use `term_paper.tex`, `term_paper.bib`, ...

Comment: BibTeX definitely doesn't allow spaces in file names.

Answer (score 5):

BibTeX doesn't accept spaces in file names. I don't think anybody would touch the sources to make it “modern style”, so there's nothing to do except removing spaces from `.bib` file names.